# How do I actually begin to code, in Node, using the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, javascript, node.js

I am a noob at coding, so forgive me for this rather trivial question.

I am trying to make a program that can access the Stack Exchange API. Specifically I want to make a program that gets live question feed (preferably as a question object) from any Stack Exchange site of my choice.

I have scoured the Stack Exchange API page but I'm not able to understand how to exactly code it. I usually learn by examples. For example, I know that to access `discord.js` I write in my JS code as:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    //code to deal with message
});

bot.login('BOT-TOKEN-HERE');
```

Is there any standard template such as the example I gave for API Stack Exchange? For certain, I'm sure we would have `require('stackexchange-node');` (I believe `stackexchange-node` is the official SE npm package) and as well as a constructor.

Comment: Dd this help? [How to call the API via JSONP in Plain Old JavaScript](//stackapps.com/q/891)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thanks for finding that, but unfortunately that doesn't help me much. I use node.js, and that is a browser version of the code.

Comment: There is now [a Node library for the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/8079/node-js-chatexchange-an-api-for-chat).

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of how to invoke the constructor [here](https://github.com/oicramps/stackoverflow-answers-graphql-api/blob/master/src/resolvers.js):

```
// app/src/resolvers.js
const stackexchange = require('stackexchange-node');
const config = require('../config/config');

const options = {version: 2.2};
const context = new stackexchange(options);

const API_KEY = config['API_KEY'];

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        questions: async (root, {tagged, limit, sort, score}) => {
           var result;

           await _getQuestionsByFilter(tagged, limit, sort, score).then(function (data) {
               result = data.items;
           });

           return result;
        }
    },
};

async function _getQuestionsByFilter (tagged, limit, sort, score) {
    return await _getQuestionsStackExchangeApi(tagged, limit, sort, score);
}

function _getQuestionsStackExchangeApi(tagged, limit, sort, score) {
    let filter = {
        key: API_KEY,
        pagesize: limit,
        tagged: tagged,
        sort: sort,
        score: score,
        order: 'asc'
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        context.questions.questions(filter, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(results);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {resolvers};
```

As well as [an example](https://github.com/JustCodeBlog/coding-companion/blob/master/src/services/stackoverflow.ts)
which uses TypeScript.

**References**

- [stackoverflow-answers-graphql-api Github repo: resolvers.js](https://github.com/sgml/stackoverflow-answers-graphql-api/blob/master/src/resolvers.js)
- [coding-companion Github repo: stackoverflow.ts](https://github.com/JustCodeBlog/coding-companion/blob/master/src/services/stackoverflow.ts)