# Node.js/ChatExchange - An API for Chat

Tags: library, chat, node.js

### About

ChatExchange is a node.js API for talking to Stack Exchange chat (Largely based on [ChatExchange](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange) for python). This is still very much in the works, but currently provides a working API for those who wish to connect to chat and send/receive basic messages.
Currently looking for interested developers who want to provide input and utilize this framework in their apps.

### Code Snippet

```js
const Client = require('chatexchange');

const main = async () => {
    const client = new Client('stackoverflow.com');

    await client.login('EMAIL', 'PASSWORD');

    const me = await client.getMe();

    const room = await client.joinRoom(167908);

    room.on('message', async msg => {
        console.log('Got Message', msg);

        // eventType 8 (Someone has messaged me)
        if (msg.eventType === 8 && msg.targetUserId === me.id) {
            await msg.reply('Hello World!');
        }
    });

    // Connect to the room, and listen for new events
    await room.watch();
}

main();
```

#### Download

Available through [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), you can simply download with:

```
$ npm i chatexchange
```

#### License

All code is licensed under GPL-3.0.

### Code

You can find all the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/danbopes/chatexchange).

Documentation can be found [here](https://danbopes.github.io/chatexchange/).