# SpotDetector - A bot designed to seek out potentially bad first post/late answer reviews

Tags: app, chat

### Spotdetector

[image]

### About

A bot designed to seek out and provide feedback to moderators about potentially bad reviews.

### Check it out

You can find it currently active in the [SOBotics Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) currently running under the user [SpotDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10162108/spotdetector).

#### License

All code is licensed under GPL-3.0.

### Code

Written in Node.js, utilizing [ChatExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/8079/node-js-chatexchange-an-api-for-chat). You can find the source code on [GitHub here](https://github.com/SOBotics/SpotDetector).

Comment: **SO mods:** I have a userscript for pulling additional mod-only details for the users listed in the reports: [DeletedReviewsReportHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-userscripts/blob/master/DeletedReviewsReportHelper.user.js)

Comment: does this run on all sites or only SO?

Comment: Hi! we can move to a chatroom if you like. Yes, I wouldn't mind having it run on the site I moderate. I realize that we are a low-traffic, low-volume site, but the mod tools are a bit clunky in this department.